# Error: Tomcat 7 Configuration as Windows Service via tomcat7.exe

Tags: windows, tomcat, windows-services, tomcat7

I am attempting to run tomcat as a service.  I am able to run it succesfully when I specify just a startpath or just jvmoptions.  However, if I have both I am receiving the following error:

```
2013-04-25 11:34:01 Commons Daemon procrun stderr initialized
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:236)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:426)
```

The commands I am running are as follows:

```
service.bat install WebServices
tomcat7 //US//WebServices --Startup=auto --DisplayName="Web Services"
tomcat7 //US//WebServices --StartPath="C:\Program Files\engine" 
tomcat7 //US//WebServices --JvmOptions="-Xmx4g;-XX:PermSize=2048m;-XX:MaxPermSize=2048m"
```

As I stated, the service starts fine if I don't run the JvmOptions line, and it successfully writes log files to my startpath directory.  Then if I don't include startpath it will also run correctly, and it just won't output to the startpath.  The error only occurs when both variables are set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that when I was changing the start path and assigning variables it was losing track of catalina home.  So I added

```
-Dcatalina.home=apacheInstallLoc;-Dcatalina.base=apacheInstallLoc
```

to my JvmOptions and everything worked.